# Unable to open ... for writing: Disk quota exceeded

Tags: wordpress, хостинг

При загрузке фотографий в миниатюры появилась запись:

> Warning: imagejpeg() [function.imagejpeg]: Unable to open '/home/u907847766/public_html/wp-content/themes/News/gavern/cache_nsp/a812aad5fda59d718d2d89dbf0fd417d-widget_gk_nsp-18.jpg' for writing: Disk quota exceeded in /home/u907847766/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-image-editor.php on line 425.

Как ее устранить? Посмотрел на втором сайте: все тоже самое, только нет такого предупреждения.

Comment: Disk quota exceeded --> Дисковая квота превышена. Место на диске для вас закончилось видимо.

Answer (score 0):

> Disk quota exceeded

администратором сервера [установлена дисковая квота](https://www.opennet.ru/base/sys/linux_disk_quota2.txt.html) для вашего пользователя (`u907847766`) — размер дискового пространства, занимаего файлами/каталогами, принадлежащими этому пользователю, не должен превышать установленного предела.

вы достигли этого предела и, соответственно, при попытке ещё что-нибудь записать на диск, получаете озвученную в вопросе ошибку.

---

либо самостоятельно удалите неиспользуемые файлы/каталоги, либо обратитесь к администратору с запросом на увеличение/отмену квоты (скорее всего, это платная услуга).